# Xcode crashes with divide by zero

Tags: xcode, crash, divide-by-zero

I downloaded urlcache.zip from http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/URLCache/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008061

I opened the project in xcode and clicked on urlcacheconection.m and started scrolling down with the arrow key and xcode crashed with <see below dashed line>.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Steve : - )

```
------------------------------------------------------
Process:         Xcode [928]
Path:            /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.Xcode
Version:         3.2.1 (1613)
Build Info:      DevToolsIDE-16130000~2
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [144]

Date/Time:       2009-11-12 19:28:47.884 -0600
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.2 (10C540)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          93379 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           16
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  94960 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   11
Anonymous UUID:                      0E282DA4-7FD4-4E36-9DE6-BB0D55B04074

Exception Type:  EXC_ARITHMETIC (SIGFPE)
Exception Codes: EXC_I386_DIV (divide by zero)
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc[928]: garbage collection is ON

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.Xcode.XcodeEdit       0x00000001014bdd39 -[XCTextStorage(XCEditIndentation) columnForPositionConvertingTabs:] + 217
1   com.apple.Xcode.XcodeEdit       0x00000001014acdde -[XCFoldingTextStorage columnForPositionConvertingTabs:] + 30
2   ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001009abcae -[PBXTextFileEditor columnLocationOfCursor] + 78
3   ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008dbfe8 -[PBXFileNavigator lineBrowser:titleAtRow:inColumn:forMenu:] + 536
4   ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008dbdc8 -[PBXLineBrowser _askDataSourceForTitleAtRow:inColumn:forMenu:] + 88
5   ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008dbc01 -[PBXLineBrowser _reloadSelectionInColumnCache:column:] + 65
6   ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008e03bd -[PBXLineBrowser reloadSelection] + 125
7   ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008e024a -[PBXFileNavigator editorSelectionDidChange] + 42
8   ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008e01bf -[XCEditFileEditor textViewDidChangeSelection:] + 175
9   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86d7485a _nsnote_callback + 167
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87ff4e3a __CFXNotificationPost + 954
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe13e8 _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 200
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86d6b7c4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 101
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81d35844 -[NSTextView(NSSharing) setSelectedRanges:affinity:stillSelecting:] + 5446
14  com.apple.Xcode.XcodeEdit       0x000000010148d7aa -[XCTextView(FoldingSupport) setSelectedRanges:affinity:stillSelecting:] + 522
15  ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008dff02 -[XCSourceCodeTextView setSelectedRanges:affinity:stillSelecting:] + 66
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81e2e9f4 -[NSTextView(NSKeyBindingCommands) _moveDown:] + 595
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81e2e758 -[NSTextView(NSKeyBindingCommands) moveDown:] + 404
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81da9c91 -[NSTextView doCommandBySelector:] + 293
19  com.apple.Xcode.XcodeEdit       0x000000010148f4e2 -[XCTextView(FoldingSupport) doCommandBySelector:] + 1250
20  ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008e4633 -[XCSourceCodeTextView doCommandBySelector:] + 99
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81d9e613 -[NSKeyBindingManager(NSKeyBindingManager_MultiClients) interpretEventAsCommand:forClient:] + 1966
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81d9db24 -[NSTextInputContext handleEvent:] + 737
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81d9d7d6 -[NSView interpretKeyEvents:] + 186
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81d9d5af -[NSTextView keyDown:] + 819
25  ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008e3ec3 -[XCSourceCodeTextView keyDown:] + 99
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81d0f3af -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 8769
27  ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008c695d -[XCWindow sendEvent:] + 189
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81c43e22 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4719
29  ...ple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface  0x00000001008677bd -[PBXExtendedApplication sendEvent:] + 301
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81bda796 -[NSApplication run] + 474
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff81bd3468 NSApplicationMain + 364
32  com.apple.Xcode                 0x000000010000e97e 0x100000000 + 59774
33  com.apple.Xcode                 0x0000000100001844 0x100000000 + 6212

Thread 1:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df6bba kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df8a85 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 154
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df875c _dispatch_queue_invoke + 185
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df8286 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 244
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df7bb8 _pthread_wqthread + 353
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df7a55 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82ddde3a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82dde4ad mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe87a2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe7c2f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86df44cf +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 297
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86d74e99 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16f8e _pthread_start + 331
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16e41 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e219e2 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 10
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8800a242 __CFSocketManager + 818
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16f8e _pthread_start + 331
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16e41 thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82ddde3a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82dde4ad mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe87a2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe7c2f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x00000001167ff0e7 -[DTDKInstallBundleController fsEventsThread] + 263
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86d74e99 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16f8e _pthread_start + 331
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16e41 thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82ddde3a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82dde4ad mach_msg + 59
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe87a2 __CFRunLoopRun + 1698
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff87fe7c2f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 575
4   com.apple.DTDeviceKit           0x0000000116807094 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 229
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86d74e99 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
6   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16f8e _pthread_start + 331
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16e41 thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e189ee __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e1c7f1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1286
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000100132e14 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 372
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86d74e99 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16f8e _pthread_start + 331
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16e41 thread_start + 13

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e189ee __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e1c7f1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1286
2   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000100132e14 -[XCInvocationQueue _processInvocationsInThreadSlotNumber:] + 372
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff86d74e99 __NSThread__main__ + 1429
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16f8e _pthread_start + 331
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16e41 thread_start + 13

Thread 8:  JavaScriptCore: FastMalloc scavenger
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e189ee __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e1c7f1 _pthread_cond_wait + 1286
2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83d1e2b3 WTF::TCMalloc_PageHeap::scavengerThread() + 515
3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff83d1e2f9 WTF::TCMalloc_PageHeap::runScavengerThread(void*) + 9
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16f8e _pthread_start + 331
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82e16e41 thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df79da __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df7dec _pthread_wqthread + 917
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff82df7a55 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x000000000000002b  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x00000002002ee7a0  rsi: 0x0000000000000100  rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfe640  rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfe610
   r8: 0x00007fff70ec7560   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fff86d6780a  r11: 0x00007fff86d7a374
  r12: 0x0000000000000112  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00000002002ee7a0  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00000001014bdd39  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x000000010201f000

Binary Images:
       0x100000000 -        0x100024ff7  com.apple.Xcode 3.2.1 (1613) <D7C74A19-2392-75EE-2453-043F17B4AB54> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x100037000 -        0x100062ff7  com.apple.DevToolsFoundation 3.1 (1612) <59AF69C5-97A9-57BC-D8C7-C51B8D8BED46> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsFoundation
       0x100082000 -        0x10009efff  com.apple.JavaKit 5.1 (1591) <283271C2-DF8F-2E9C-3FA1-B1AA939B288A> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaKit.framework/Versions/A/JavaKit
       0x1000b2000 -        0x10054efff  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore 5.1 (1614) <16F61431-05C3-4134-E5E1-45BC1128079E> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsCore
       0x1007cf000 -        0x100810ff7  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsSupport 5.1 (1591) <41337C32-36D9-33E2-E49C-D5E4511EEB5F> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsSupport.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsSupport
       0x10083c000 -        0x100845fff  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsRemoteClient 5.1 (1613) <E94B6524-CB4F-92AA-4846-FDD3275B5E2D> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsRemoteClient
       0x100850000 -        0x100f4bfff  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsInterface 5.1 (1613) <06E3D36E-8DC0-64AD-7CD9-32A4DC67C1F4> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsInterface.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsInterface
       0x10133e000 -        0x1013fdfff  com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCParsing 5.1 (1591) <33B6D0B9-053A-C091-8CC6-152934295FFA> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCParsing.framework/Versions/A/DevToolsCParsing
       0x101463000 -        0x1014f1ff7  com.apple.Xcode.XcodeEdit 3.1 (1611) <8C06428D-3259-AC37-1D2B-D23A46D4C23D> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XcodeEdit.framework/Versions/A/XcodeEdit
       0x101536000 -        0x10157aff7  com.apple.DocSetAccess 2.1 (1602) <C6F9AF22-C60D-9D8A-0C86-34575F9B9270> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DocSetAccess.framework/Versions/A/DocSetAccess
       0x1015a3000 -        0x1015f2ff7  com.apple.Xdesign.XDBase 3.1 (1614) <2D587794-4B38-33C0-18A2-81C36F27B5FA> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XDBase.framework/Versions/A/XDBase
       0x101632000 -        0x10164afff  com.apple.DocSetManagement 1.0 (1612) <5201FE15-8B68-F63E-4D8B-376FA11D7D14> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DocSetManagement.framework/Versions/A/DocSetManagement
       0x10165b000 -        0x101692fff  com.apple.DocSetViewing 1.0 (1612) <43FA8BAD-DED7-C4C4-DDF3-115367623550> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DocSetViewing.framework/Versions/A/DocSetViewing
       0x101f4a000 -        0x101f54fff  com.apple.xdmappingmodel 3.1 (1614) <93921727-E43B-E76F-58D1-7867FCB08EBC> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XDMappingModel.xdplugin/Contents/MacOS/XDMappingModel
       0x101f5e000 -        0x101f5fff7  com.apple.Xdesign.XDInterface.GraphLayouter.ForceDirected 3.1 (1594) <BC9E050F-3435-FB3F-2139-522F576E8A1F> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XDInterface.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/XDForceDirectedGraphLayouter.diagramGraphLayouter/Contents/MacOS/XDForceDirectedGraphLayouter
       0x101f63000 -        0x101f64ff7  com.apple.Xdesign.XDInterface.GraphLayouter.Hierarchical 3.1 (1594) <4BD123A2-27A6-A2FB-D730-2EC3AA93DF05> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XDInterface.framework/Versions/A/PlugIns/XDHierarchicalGraphLayouter.diagramGraphLayouter/Contents/MacOS/XDHierarchicalGraphLayouter
       0x101f68000 -        0x101f70fff  libsvn_delta-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <7D7E19A8-3483-BCC6-E174-5FCF81CC309A> /usr/lib/libsvn_delta-1.0.dylib
       0x101f7c000 -        0x101f9bff7  com.apple.XdesignPlugin 3.1 (1614) <98ECF784-6A7D-D5C7-B1BC-D92204F60876> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XdesignPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/XdesignPlugin
       0x101fad000 -        0x101fbcff7  com.apple.xcode.subversion 3.1 (1605) <CDFD7C0F-7AB7-B01E-DCA6-68B4EF726EA6> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeSubversionPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/XcodeSubversionPlugin
       0x101fc8000 -        0x101fe6fff  libapr-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <77712CC8-C4CF-E0E8-B740-B55192C05CB9> /usr/lib/libapr-1.0.dylib
       0x101ff3000 -        0x101ffaff7  libsvn_diff-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <E1591459-E977-9D60-22FB-7DEF7FB97637> /usr/lib/libsvn_diff-1.0.dylib
       0x104d59000 -        0x104d99ff7  com.apple.XDSourceCode 3.1 (1591) <DE2286F6-DD15-BFD5-029E-5A786D963340> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XDClassModel.xdplugin/Contents/MacOS/XDClassModel
       0x104dbc000 -        0x104dd4fe7  libaprutil-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <3D7EBE21-7A3D-E46C-1E3E-361F98170429> /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
       0x104ddf000 -        0x104de2fff  libsvn_fs-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <DF1FA07C-899B-4D0F-2053-3CF2A607EC4F> /usr/lib/libsvn_fs-1.0.dylib
       0x104de8000 -        0x104decfff  libsvn_ra_local-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <7AE83A6B-401D-8F2D-7DB6-6D3CC1C2B34C> /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_local-1.0.dylib
       0x104df2000 -        0x104df8fff  libsvn_ra-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <17309F76-0DEB-9E53-C726-691DB946AC66> /usr/lib/libsvn_ra-1.0.dylib
       0x11542d000 -        0x11556dfef  com.apple.Xdesign.XDInterface 3.1 (1594) <10115454-F279-AC4C-CF71-4106637C5432> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XDInterface.framework/Versions/A/XDInterface
       0x115621000 -        0x115621fff  libsvn_fs_util-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <5CAD8C6E-5B71-C2FA-163C-D5CEACF5736C> /usr/lib/libsvn_fs_util-1.0.dylib
       0x115625000 -        0x115625ff7  com.apple.xcode.subversion.ui 3.1 (1605) <443F6CA9-19D7-DEF2-5965-99E7D4689F97> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeSubversionIDEPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/XcodeSubversionIDEPlugin
       0x115a77000 -        0x115ab3ff7  com.apple.xdcoredataplugin 3.1 (1612) <DA261684-0B86-E88E-EEB1-E2CDEB94F94C> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XDCoreDataModel.xdplugin/Contents/MacOS/XDCoreDataModel
       0x115ad1000 -        0x115aedff7  libsvn_fs_fs-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <E0F43797-704D-3230-72CC-BDD7C10F8FA2> /usr/lib/libsvn_fs_fs-1.0.dylib
       0x115af6000 -        0x115afafff  com.apple.xcode.perforce.ui 3.1 (1605) <96DA0162-A5AD-0BF9-E01F-9A679CF3C2EA> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodePerforceIDEPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/XcodePerforceIDEPlugin
       0x115c00000 -        0x115c34ff7  libsvn_client-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <03940D76-1F3F-292A-E9EE-BAA3BCB24F57> /usr/lib/libsvn_client-1.0.dylib
       0x115c41000 -        0x115c4fff7  libsvn_ra_svn-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <F85654AC-5729-5E6E-E2CF-B0B924B8A246> /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_svn-1.0.dylib
       0x115c56000 -        0x115c75fff  libsvn_repos-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <CAF17863-5B37-681F-8BF1-BA37BEF97C8F> /usr/lib/libsvn_repos-1.0.dylib
       0x115c7e000 -        0x115cb7fff  libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <0110708C-2986-E80A-5B15-59C444FC94A5> /usr/lib/libsvn_subr-1.0.dylib
       0x115cc9000 -        0x115cffff7  libsvn_wc-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <24D9C3EC-4F21-D8F3-C450-69731C0DF0A3> /usr/lib/libsvn_wc-1.0.dylib
       0x115d0b000 -        0x115d22ff7  libsvn_ra_neon-1.0.dylib ??? (???) <89794E2C-9B90-52F1-92BC-7F91F25E2E3E> /usr/lib/libsvn_ra_neon-1.0.dylib
       0x115d2c000 -        0x115d44fe7  libneon.27.dylib ??? (???) <73ED20C9-D5E5-45FD-6F3A-953053F698D9> /usr/lib/libneon.27.dylib
       0x115d4f000 -        0x115d63fff  com.apple.xcode.perforce 3.1 (1605) <69932CF9-3796-ACB7-D0CE-98AE814FCF13> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodePerforcePlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/XcodePerforcePlugin
       0x115d6f000 -        0x115d89ff7  com.apple.xcode.cvs 3.1 (1605) <45675BEF-778B-C56D-C8B7-58005FAB6A8C> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeCVSPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/XcodeCVSPlugin
       0x115d98000 -        0x115d9bfff  com.apple.xcode.cvs.ui 3.1 (1605) <3CED76D6-B22F-7519-BAAA-DDA430FE14BE> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/XcodeCVSIDEPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/XcodeCVSIDEPlugin
       0x115d9f000 -        0x115da8fff  com.apple.Xcode.PlistPlugin 3.2 (1607) <78483015-B132-3C4E-FA1D-3DB174C014B5> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/PlistPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/PlistPlugin
       0x115db0000 -        0x115dd8ff7  com.apple.Xcode.PlistEdit 3.2 (1607) <7A5E054A-CF20-8607-C870-502A8197BFF5> /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlistEdit.framework/Versions/A/PlistEdit
       0x115df0000 -        0x115e01fff  com.apple.Xcode.BuildSettingsPanes 5.1 (1613) <8A715CAB-6393-3740-3953-ADB8DFE44010> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/BuildSettingsPanes.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/BuildSettingsPanes
       0x115e0b000 -        0x115e0cff7  com.apple.Xcode.iPhoneSimulatorLaunchPlugin 2.0 (28) <C0780C3B-9AE8-24A8-7365-1CEAE17142C1> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneSimulatorLaunchPlugin.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneSimulatorLaunchPlugin
       0x115e14000 -        0x115e14ff7  com.apple.xcode.plug-in.CoreBuildTasks 3.0 (1614) <FFE8D711-3E24-7CE9-E221-BC153AA97B4D> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/CoreBuildTasks
       0x115e18000 -        0x115e23ff7  com.apple.platform.iphoneos.plugin 1.0 (1.0) <18433CEB-2F42-F2C7-E587-123816737C2C> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneOS Build System Support
       0x115e2f000 -        0x115e35ff7  com.apple.AppleScriptStudio.ASKPlugin 1.7 (68) <45690C0A-0795-9C3B-94D1-801FC72D0ABE> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/ASKPlugin.pbplugin/Contents/MacOS/ASKPlugin
       0x115e3f000 -        0x115e95fff  com.apple.AppleScriptKit 1.5.1 (81) <F7FCBE73-EB73-A574-A9C7-C343E2562B78> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppleScriptKit.framework/Versions/A/AppleScriptKit
       0x115eed000 -        0x115f34ff7  com.apple.OSAKit 1.2.1 (76) <C5F739FF-07F8-2172-80FA-9885962034F8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OSAKit.framework/Versions/A/OSAKit
       0x115f6a000 -        0x115f77fe7  libexslt.0.dylib ??? (???) <D9944F04-1F01-B9D1-A46F-96229CD19437> /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib
       0x115f7d000 -        0x115f80ff7  com.apple.AppleScriptStudio.ASKDictionaryPlugin 1.6 (68) <C8206D3D-6400-C20C-09CD-D10D33ACCA61> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/ASKDictionaryPlugin.pbplugin/Contents/MacOS/ASKDictionaryPlugin
       0x115f87000 -        0x115f91fff  com.apple.AppleScriptStudio.ASKDebuggerPlugin 1.6 (68) <704A64D0-E992-58D5-090B-7A936BE63FE9> /Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/ASKDebuggerPlugin.pbplugin/Contents/MacOS/ASKDebuggerPlugin
       0x115faa000 -        0x115fddfff  com.apple.Xcode.JavaDebugging 5.1 (1613) <9C5174D5-94DC-D972-2EC0-38E3A5A370B7> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/JavaDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/JavaDebugging
       0x115fff000 -        0x11606ffff  com.apple.Xcode.GDBMIDebuggingPlugin 5.1 (1613) <07A4DC4D-78A9-DD1B-767B-E94345A7EC59> /Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/GDBMIDebugging.xcplugin/Contents/MacOS/GDBMIDebugging
       0x1160b5000 -        0x1160c3ff7  com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase 3.1 (88.2) <9D8648DF-BD6C-BC51-8B4B-D7E9742E3EE0> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/DTDeviceKitBase
       0x1160cf000 -        0x11611ffe3  com.apple.mobiledevice 251.6 (251.6) <43C0DF98-BE1A-7CE8-7A00-C1A5115E1BB5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice
       0x116142000 -        0x116228fe7  libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???) <A60E5A1D-EA38-DB7E-39C1-D29938E46691> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.7.dylib
       0x116280000 -        0x1162acfe7  libssl.0.9.7.dylib ??? (???) <C1562D55-DA52-E37E-BD42-BA6BEFC2541B> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.7.dylib
       0x1163c4000 -        0x1163d6fff  com.apple.DeviceLinkX 3.0 (153) /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DeviceLink.framework/Versions/A/DeviceLink
       0x1163e2000 -        0x1163e5fff  com.apple.Xcode.iPhoneSimulatorDevicePlugin 2.0 (28) <6F1E9280-B6F2-B145-64DA-B0789E83DD81> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneSimulatorDevicePlugin.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneSimulatorDevicePlugin
       0x1163ec000 -        0x1163f3fff  com.apple.iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient 2.0 (14) <482219C5-85F0-64D5-0767-0BCDA1F351F9> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework/Versions/A/iPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient
       0x116753000 -        0x1167a1ff7  com.apple.Xcode.iPhoneSupport 3.1 (179) <59C87A3A-4183-9CBB-D0F5-1512AB69ACAA> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneRemoteDevice.xcodeplugin/Contents/MacOS/iPhoneRemoteDevice
       0x1167f2000 -        0x116818fff  com.apple.DTDeviceKit 3.1 (88.2) <8D295F54-9B18-8DF6-4ECF-2037E12CF7EE> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/DTDeviceKit
    0x7fff5fc00000 -     0x7fff5fc3bdef  dyld 132.1 (???) <B633F790-4DDB-53CD-7ACF-2A3682BCEA9F> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff80003000 -     0x7fff8004cff7  com.apple.securityinterface 4.0.1 (37214) <F8F2D8F4-861F-6694-58F6-3DC55C9DBF50> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityInterface.framework/Versions/A/SecurityInterface
    0x7fff8004d000 -     0x7fff8006fff7  com.apple.opencl 12 (12) <533D6753-D6E4-EC34-E93B-8F6498B50FBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL
    0x7fff80070000 -     0x7fff800edfe7  com.apple.CoreText 3.1.0 (???) <B4BFF82D-CA77-9A8E-2C7E-66367E807C7C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff800ef000 -     0x7fff8016aff7  com.apple.ISSupport 1.9.2 (50) <09D926B6-BBF7-7E15-2978-D0C4D933543D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ISSupport.framework/Versions/A/ISSupport
    0x7fff801b0000 -     0x7fff801c6fff  com.apple.ImageCapture 6.0 (6.0) <5B5AF8FB-C12A-B51F-94FC-3EC4698E818E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageCapture.framework/Versions/A/ImageCapture
    0x7fff80402000 -     0x7fff805bcfef  com.apple.ImageIO.framework 3.0.1 (3.0.1) <10202E28-34DD-71CA-BE5D-1BE5C8DE2198> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
    0x7fff805bd000 -     0x7fff8063afef  com.apple.backup.framework 1.2 (1.2) <E3635A09-6221-71CE-6083-6025CE478634> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
    0x7fff807c2000 -     0x7fff807cfff7  com.apple.AppleFSCompression 1.0 (1.0) <06099990-D14E-CBD3-8E6A-23905A3B4A48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleFSCompression.framework/Versions/A/AppleFSCompression
    0x7fff807d0000 -     0x7fff8120dfe7  com.apple.WebCore 6531.21 (6531.21.8) <0DD00A3A-81DE-8CEE-67B8-65C06E8C6B1A> /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/WebCore
    0x7fff8120e000 -     0x7fff81306fe7  libiconv.2.dylib ??? (???) <ECEE3D93-B5E3-F0E0-803E-CA3DC3B33D57> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff81307000 -     0x7fff813b6fff  edu.mit.Kerberos 6.5.9 (6.5.9) <42364D54-C647-14DE-2B1C-D94DAA03F092> /System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Versions/A/Kerberos
    0x7fff813b7000 -     0x7fff8163cff7  com.apple.security 6.0 (36910) <67DF686D-B991-D0D6-20B6-9EA668018466> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff8163d000 -     0x7fff81640ff7  libCoreVMClient.dylib ??? (???) <1C6D04BA-5F78-CC4D-26CB-7904919042B9> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff81691000 -     0x7fff816d2ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration 1.10.1 (1.10.1) <FFCA91A7-ADDB-E3D0-234A-47609BC37556> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff816d3000 -     0x7fff8190dfff  com.apple.AddressBook.framework 5.0.1 (864) <4FA65C25-3F4F-6D79-1901-07FF6BBAAEDB> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/Versions/A/AddressBook
    0x7fff8190e000 -     0x7fff81943ff7  libcups.2.dylib ??? (???) <0D020D80-F9D5-55DE-9CCE-9B80CDF08FC4> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff81944000 -     0x7fff81b27ff7  libType1Scaler.dylib ??? (???) <2B6581FB-7C0B-AE43-7F16-694587B58136> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libType1Scaler.dylib
    0x7fff81b28000 -     0x7fff81bc2fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS 4.1 (???) <E2A107C5-0230-265A-E40D-CFE0219C99E1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff81bc3000 -     0x7fff81bceff7  com.apple.speech.recognition.framework 3.11.1 (3.11.1) <F0DDF27E-DB55-07CE-E548-C62095BE8167> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
    0x7fff81bd1000 -     0x7fff825c5fff  com.apple.AppKit 6.6.3 (1038.25) <2F7A5AC8-29E7-9B5F-D3F1-4C7F5821BB80> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff825e0000 -     0x7fff82615fff  libGLImage.dylib ??? (???) <8AB3A26A-4CC4-4E6D-95CC-530FD7204599> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff8278e000 -     0x7fff8299aff7  com.apple.RawCamera.bundle 2.2.1 (477) <B4DD9D3B-CD05-5ACE-6808-BEC5660D805C> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/Contents/MacOS/RawCamera
    0x7fff829e6000 -     0x7fff82b04ff7  com.apple.PubSub 1.0.4 (65.11) <C1D56F85-7553-FB97-2A31-35CEB2BB8B63> /System/Library/Frameworks/PubSub.framework/Versions/A/PubSub
    0x7fff82b05000 -     0x7fff82b4fff7  com.apple.Metadata 10.6.2 (507.4) <A28A5E0C-DCDC-A5CE-4EB7-39752E63956A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff82b50000 -     0x7fff82b96fe7  libvDSP.dylib ??? (???) <2DAA1591-8AE8-B411-7D01-68DE99C63CEE> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff82bdf000 -     0x7fff82bdfff7  com.apple.Accelerate 1.5 (Accelerate 1.5) <E517A811-E0E6-89D0-F397-66122C7A25A4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff82c9b000 -     0x7fff82cd5fff  com.apple.bom 10.0 (164) <E5C9AFBD-68C1-197E-72B0-B43295DC87DC> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Versions/A/Bom
    0x7fff82cd6000 -     0x7fff82ce8fe7  libsasl2.2.dylib ??? (???) <76B83C8D-8EFE-4467-0F75-275648AFED97> /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
    0x7fff82d6a000 -     0x7fff82ddcfef  com.apple.CoreSymbolication 2.0 (23) <06F8561E-4B36-7BF6-31BA-64091B3D8058> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSymbolication.framework/Versions/A/CoreSymbolication
    0x7fff82ddd000 -     0x7fff82f9bff7  libSystem.B.dylib ??? (???) <526DD3E5-2A8B-4512-ED97-01B832369959> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x7fff82f9c000
```

Comment: whoa whoa whoa there... Submit the bug report to apple? This is waaaaaaaay long for here, I think. I'm not saying don't post, but I doubt you'll get any info from people here that Apple cannot provide.

Comment: Seems a bug with Xcode, it happened a lot with Tiger.

Answer (score 2):

Open ~/Library/Preferences/ and move com.apple.Xcode.plist to your desktop, then relaunch Xcode.  Then attach the moved-aside file to a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com.  It looks like you have an indentation setting set to a zero value.

Comment: You Sir, are a genius.  That fixed it.  I have had this going on for a few days.  Again, thank you so much.